# Carbon Fibre Frame Paint Chip from Stuck chain

Tags: carbon, damage

My chain got stuck between smallest chainring and carbon fibre frame.. The paint chipped in one place and there is a half mm scratch in another place..

What is the chance that it damaged the carbon fibre? In the chip think the carbon fibre is exposed.. It doesnt look damaged to..

I am planning to seal this with Araldite...

[image: Chip1]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great work for including plenty of photos.  I can't answer cos I don't own carbon.  What can you do to stop this happening again?

Answer (score 1):

To literally answer your question, Yes the carbon is damaged.

Considering it's exposed and because carbon consist of many filaments bonded together, you can also say it's integrity has been affected. The degree of damage however, is not easily determined by visual only inspection.

Sealing it with epoxy is a good idea to stop any contaminants and further fiber damage, but not a good fix for integrity.

When you get to proper damage assessment, you start looking at ultrasound and x-ray and a lot of $. Carbon has the tendency to 'flare' out on the inside on the tube. Consider the impact on the outside as a force and that would transfer through and push the fibers out on the inside. This is the bit you can't see and the dangerous part of carbon damage.

If you really want to know what the condition is like, you will need to get it to a proper carbon repairer. I say proper because there are many on the market that will 'fix' it by simply repainting and clearcoating it so it looks fixed. It's pretty cheap, but you need to understand what you pay for and how much you value your face IF the repair fails.

Answer (score 0):

the BB area is usually very strong with much thicker layers compared to the rest of the frame, you do have alot of exposed fibers, you have to cover them up with UV resistant coating or the epoxy will degrade over time causing the fiber bonding to lose strength